# Не работает scale_color_brewer

Tags: r, ggplot2

Требуется написать код, чтобы получить график, как на картинке; попробовала код

```
    ggplot(data=cuckoos, aes(x=species, y=length)) 
    + stat_summary(geom='pointrange', fun.data = mean_cl_normal) + theme_dark() 
    + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),legend.position="none") 
    + scale_color_brewer(palette='Set1')
```

все, кроме палитры, работает; подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### система, проверяющая задания, указывает, что "не та переменная управляет цветом"

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что не заданы изначально разные цвета в aes. Попробуйте так:

```
    ggplot(data=diamonds[1:100,], aes(x = color, y = carat, colour = factor(color))) + 
      stat_summary(geom='pointrange', fun.data = mean_cl_normal) + theme_dark() + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),legend.position="none") + 
      scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```